# Excel, How to get last value in second column for a name selected in first column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel sheet in below state:

```
Column1     Column2
A              10
X              20
C              30
D             -45
A              50
B              61
C             -08
D             -15
```

Here I want the formula to select the unique names from Column1 and with respect to that grab the last value from column2.

For example:
Expected output

```
Column11       Column21
A                 50
B                 61
C                -08
D                -15
X                 20
```

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have to tried to use Vlookup but not able to figure out a way to get this output. I saw people asking questions related to excel here, so asked one.

Comment: Please share the formula(s) you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in columns **A** and **B** like:

[image]

In **C1** enter:

```
=A1
```

and in **C2** enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$14,INT(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$1:$A$14)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$14)+(COLUMN($A$1:$A$14)*0.01)),1)),100*MOD(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$1:$A$14)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$14)+(COLUMN($A$1:$A$14)*0.01)),1),1)),"")
```

and copy down.  This will extract the unique values from column **A**.  In **D1** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:$A$8=C1),$B$1:$B$8)
```

and copy down.  Column **D** is kind of like *VLOOKUP()*, except it retrieves the **last** match rather than the **first**.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

For an explanation of the *LOOKUP()* formula, see:

[simoco's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205575/find-last-match-in-column-using-built-in-functions-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Would you mind explaining the `1/($a$1:$a$8=c1)` in the `lookup` formula? I've never seen a slash used like that.

Comment: @Dane  See my **EDIT#1**